# Query related to Log4j2 - Delay in execution

Tags: java, log4j2

By adding this line of code in my class file, the execution of code is getting delayed by 5000 ms.

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ReadDataFromPGDB.class);
```

If I comment and use normal STDOUT then code executes in around ~150ms. With above statement it takes around ~5150 ms.

Why is it taking so much time to execute by adding logger?

Am I doing it correctly?

Kindly help.

Comment: 1. How did you test your code? How many times? 2. Complex log configuration, specially including socket, database connection, may take up some time.

Comment: I am automation scripts using selenium. In every class file this statement is defined.

Comment: There is no more configuration that i have done apart from specifying the log4j2.xml file.